# Centroid of a solid polygon vs vertices on a polygon

Tags: geometry

The centroid of a solid triangle coincides with that of three equal point masses on the three vertices. Will that be the case for generic polygons other than triangular ones? How should we understand why the above mentioned coincidences happen to be true for triangles? Must be due to linearity but is there a more convincing proof?

Comment: The centroid of a triangular frame is NOT the same as the centroid of its vertices.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca beg to differ?

Comment: Example: a triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(0,2)$. The centroid of its sides is $${2(0,1)+2(1,0)+2\sqrt2(1,1)\over4+2\sqrt2}\ne{(2,2)\over3}.$$

Comment: This is also called the "Spieker center" of the triangle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spieker_center

Comment: @Intelligentipauca  Thanks so much for the new Information. So I should reedit my question. Rather than comparison between a solid triangle and triangular edges, but between a solid triangle and three vertices.